# RewriteRule not triggering 404 and not 410 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule ^http:\/\/www.example.com\/word-lists\/words-that-end-with\/letter\/[a-z0-9]{2,}$ [NC,R=410,L]
```

**[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yL7pK3/1)**

I have checked my htaccess file and there is nothing in there that would override this rule that I can see. For some reason pages that should trigger this rule are not and sending me to a 404 instead.

Example Trigger URL: http://www.example.com/word-lists/words-that-end-with/letter/hdfdf

Do I need a RewriteCond Rule before this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the HTTP_HOST from your.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule ^/?word-lists/words-that-end-with/letter/[a-z0-9]{2,}$ - [NC,R=410,L]
```

Comment: Your rule was also missing the 2nd perameter **RewritePath** I added a **-** ,it means the request will be handled without redirection.

Comment: @Starkeen I was about to submit the answer and you nailed it :D

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return 410 instead, then use [G] flag

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^word-lists/words-that-end-with/letter/[a-z0-9]{2,}$ - [G]
```

Comment: I actually changed it to `G` shortly before I saw this answer lol. Good job to both of you. Wish I could share the answers